# JavaFX - styling an unfocused ListView row

Tags: css, listview, javafx, focus, styling

I am trying to style a selected, unfocused ListView row with a different color (say gray). I found this useful [CSS snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641478/javafx-css-styling-listview) to be very useful, but it lacks the very needed behavior for coloring the selection differently when out of focus.

```
/*
1. Odd rows with white background color;
2. ListView: when mouse over an item, highlight with a blue shade;
3. ListView: when an item is selected, paint it with a gradient;
4. ListView: when focus is lost from ListView, selected item should be painted with gradient;
5. ListView: all items will start with text-fill black. But on mouse over and/or selected it will change to white.
*/

.list-cell:filled:selected:focused, .list-cell:filled:selected {
    /* 3:, 4: */
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#333 0%, #777 25%, #aaa 75%, #eee 100%);
    -fx-text-fill: white; /* 5 */
}
.list-cell { -fx-text-fill: black; /* 5 */ }
.list-cell:odd { -fx-background-color: white; /* 1 */ }
.list-cell:even { -fx-background-color: #8f8; /* for information */ }
.list-cell:filled:hover { 
    -fx-background-color: #00f; /* 2 */
    -fx-text-fill: white; /* 5 */
}
```

Namely, how is Comment # 4 above implemented? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way a list-cell becomes both selected and not in focus is if the ListView it is part of loses focus. With that in mind two css classes should be created for each condition with one including ListView's css selector (list-view).

```
.list-cell:filled:selected {
    /* 4: (Styling when out of focus)*/
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#333 0%, #777 25%, #aaa 75%, #eee 100%);
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.list-view:focused .list-cell:filled:selected {
    /* 3: (This is more specific and therefore overrides the above)*/
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#300 0%, #700 25%, #a00 75%, #e00 100%);
}
```