# ListView styling a selected item text-fill - JavaFX 8 MAGIC or BUG?

Tags: java, css, listview, javafx

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641478/javafx-css-styling-listview) and get this code from answer:

```
.list-cell:filled:selected:focused, .list-cell:filled:selected {
    /* 3:, 4: */
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#333 0%, #777 25%, #aaa 75%, #eee 100%);
    -fx-text-fill: white; /* 5 */
}
.list-cell { -fx-text-fill: black; /* 5 */ }
.list-cell:odd { -fx-background-color: white; /* 1 */ }
.list-cell:even { -fx-background-color: #8f8; /* for information */ }
.list-cell:filled:hover { 
    -fx-background-color: #00f; /* 2 */
    -fx-text-fill: white; /* 5 */
}
```

I would make the selected item with black text-fill (text-color). Therefore I take these classes
 `.list-cell:filled:selected:focused, .list-cell:filled:selected`
and change attribute `-fx-text-fill` from `white` to `black`, but nothing happens, but if I change background color to red, then background color have changed (this does not apply to text color, this is just check on right classes)

How to change text color of selected item in focused ListView?

**UPD1:**
I tried to change text color of list-cell just in this variant:

```
.list-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: magenta;
}
```

and this variant:

```
.list-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:filled{
    -fx-text-fill: magenta;
}
```

but nothing works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the following code and it works just fine on Java 8. It changes the text color of the selected cell.

**ListViewSample.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewSample extends Application {

    ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "chocolate", "salmon", "gold", "coral", "darkorchid",
            "darkgoldenrod", "lightsalmon", "black", "rosybrown", "blue",
            "blueviolet", "brown");
    final Label label = new Label();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox box = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("list.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("ListViewSample");
        box.getChildren().addAll(list, label);
        VBox.setVgrow(list, Priority.ALWAYS);

        label.setLayoutX(10);
        label.setLayoutY(115);
        label.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
        list.setItems(data);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**list.css**

```
.list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

This also works :

```
.list-cell:filled:selected:focused, .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#328BDB 0%, #207BCF 25%, #1973C9 75%, #0A65BF 100%);
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Comment: I have determined why not change color: because I set CellFactory on listView.

Comment: Ahh Congrats ! Just let the users know that css works fine, by accepting the answer :)

Comment: oh-_- I found the root of all evil. It was necessary to add a checkBox to listCell and align it on right side. For this purpose other programmer set the text of listCell null and maked hBox with label and checkBox. So background of cell have changed and text color haven't changed.

Comment: are you know a good way to add a checkBox to listCell? Just if I add checkBox to the graphics of listCell then checkBox appears just after the text of listCell. There are graphicsGap, but it's static number and if width of listCell have changed then checkBox will remain in place.

Comment: You should add a new question, whenever you have any questions instead of commenting on old questions.

Comment: I don't understand how you get it working. It does not appear to be working for me. I use setTextFill() and I continue to get white text color upon clicking listCell