# JavaFX ListCell change text color on event

Tags: listview, javafx, event-listener

I have a `ListView` with my own CellFactory implementation and an EventListener attached listening for double click on a cell:

```
listView.setOnMouseClicked(this::handleFolderClicked);
```

And the handler method:

```
private void handleFolderClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
            // change the text color of the clicked cell here
            File selectedFolder = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            // do stuff...
        }
}
```

Now my question i how can I change the text color of the double clicked cell (inside the handler method)?

Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Try the css in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25832408/1759128).

Comment: Not knowing more about what you are trying to accomplish, I'd go with a pseudoClass state change on double click and then use css to style that state. In addition to that, why do you add the event handler to your listView and not to the cell?

Comment: @JohnRW Could you please post an example?