# How can I change the background of a single cell in a JavaFX ListView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-2

I have `listView` populated with `userNames` and when one of the Users are sending me a message I want to indicate that by changing the background color of that cell while I keep the current cell selected.

Is there a way to achieve this? I haven't had time to have a look at CSS so I would prefer a programatically solution.

This is the init of the list/listView

```
    userList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    userListView = new ListView<String>();
    userListView.setItems(userList);
```

This is how I add a new User to the list:

```
userlist.add(newUserName);
```

Then there is a method called by the Eventhandler that is handling incomming messages. This is where I get the userName which I want to "highlight" on the listView.

Comment: The easiest way would be to style your `ListView` with a css-file and define an attribute, which you set for this `Cell`, when the message is received. You can find some information about this topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641478/javafx-css-styling-listview). Just like "odd" or "even", you can define your own pseudo-class (e.g. "incomingMessage") and style it via CSS accordingly. Then, within the `Cell` class, you have to add "incomingMessage" to the style class, when necessary: `this.getStyleClass().add("incomingMessage");`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i guess ill have a look at CSS then. right now I cant even figure out how to get that specific cell.

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm) might help.

Comment: Hopefully the answer posted by @Turing85 helps, but if not, it might be helpful to see some of your relevant code.

Comment: thanks guys, the link Turing provided is what I started with :). About the code example it's just really just what i described, nothing fancy.